# PHP code to generate or refresh a new Access Token for Youtube API V3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, access-token

I am new to YouTube API work and I have been generating the YouTube feeds using my PHP Code.

But every time I run the code I have to generate a new Access token since it expires every 1 hour. Now I have been trying to write a PHP code to refresh the access token and make things work. But I don't know where my code is going wrong or what I missed. Can anyone please give me a PHP code to generate or refresh the Access Token.

This is what I did till now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty examples. For instance at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php , which you need to customize.

What you seems to do wrong, is to set correctly the redirect-uri in: 
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$redirect_uri , must be an url on your own web-server which will handle the reponse (containing the tokens). Further, this url must be the same url that is registered via the API console for your CLIENT_ID: they must match.

You could, for example first set in the API console the redirect_uri to something like:

```
http://localhost/mytokencallback.php
```

and then use

```
$redirect_uri='http://localhost/mytokencallback.php';
```